# Scaling an SVG without affecting paths

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, gsap

I'm looking for some pointers on scaling SVG containers without affecting paths inside. I'm working with Greensock.js and would like the SVG containers to scale with the width of the letters themselves (without changing the aspect ratio of the paths inside). The end goal is that the surrounding letters shuffle with the scaling letter. See attached gif for expected result.

[Scaling Letters Codepen](https://codepen.io/leecranny/full/mvoXPB)
[image: Final_Result]

See the Codepen, but here is how I've set up my HTML:

```
<div class="letters">
    <svg class="lcontainer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 324 406">
        <rect class="bottom" x="46" y="353" width="278" height="53" />
        <rect width="53" height="406" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="econtainer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 324 406">
        <rect class="outer" x="46" width="278" height="53" />
        <rect class="inner" x="46" y="247" width="240" height="53" />
        <rect class="outer" x="46" y="353" width="278" height="53" />
        <rect width="54" height="406" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that makes my head hurt but I think you'll need to implement some kind of per letter animation. I'd do it in SMIL personally but you could use javascript.

Comment: I would put all the letters in the same svg element.You can place every letter relative to the bounding box of the previous group. Yet an other solution would be using svg turbulence filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, as enxaneta suggested I ended up putting all paths in one SVG and working with them in there.

My final answer is having them in groups which let me use EventListeners on both individual parts of the letters and their containers, while keeping them in the same viewBox.

Here is my Codepen for the solution:
https://codepen.io/leecranny/full/MLdBra

```
<div class="leah">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 982 408" height="400">
    <g class="hbox">
        <rect  x="797.125" width="53.55" height="408" />
        <rect id="h_middle" x="806.05" y="104.55" width="158.1" height="53.55" />
        <rect id="h_side" x="928.45" width="53.55" height="408" />
    </g>
    <g class="abox">
        <path id="a_short" d="M750.75169,405.5H698.34861V106.05385c0-29.082-18.01843-53.65077-39.34861-53.65077s-39.34861,24.56881-39.34861,53.65077V405.5H567.24831V106.05385C567.24831,47.57558,608.40754,0,659,0s91.75169,47.57558,91.75169,106.05385Z" transform="translate(0 1)"/>
        <path id="a_wide" d="M821.75169,405.5H769.34861V146.05385C769.34861,87,716,52.40308,659,52.40308S549.65139,91,549.65139,146.05385V405.5H497.24831V136.05385C497.24831,61,568,0,659,0S821.75169,55,821.75169,136.05385Z" transform="translate(0 1)"/>
        <rect id="a_middle" x="590.37692" y="299.5908" width="137.24615" height="52.40308"/>
    </g>
    <g class="ebox">
        <rect id="e_inner" x="243.03125" y="248" width="240" height="53" />
        <rect id="e_outer" x="243.03125" y="354" width="278" height="53" />
        <rect id="e_outer" x="243.03125" y="1" width="278" height="53" />
        <rect id="e_left" x="197.03125" y="1" width="54" height="406" />
    </g>
    <g class="lbox">
        <rect id="l_short" x="46" y="354" width="105" height="53" />
        <rect id="l_left" y="1" width="54" height="406" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control the SVGs you need to remake each one in such a way that you can turn the svg height/width and `viewbox` to percentages.

One example is remaking the svg with a canvas of 100px x 100px. Then if you change the units to a relative measure like `%` or `em` the points on the path are still relative because they're based on 100.

It's kind of a pain, but its the best solution I've ever found for scaling a container without messing up the paths.

Here are some [additional details with examples](https://blog.prototypr.io/svg-clip-path-sketch-what-i-learned-750b6cf36796).